# How to automate Docker container's package update

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have a container which gets built off of a Dockerfile and every time a new container gets built, I am not able to run `apt-get update`. I would get an error like `There is no public key available for the following key IDs: [some IDs]` which I know how to fix manually:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [some IDs above].
```

But is there any way I could get something added to my Dockerfile to fix this issue so I could have the `RUN apt-get update` in my Dockerfile run properly

Thanks

Comment: Updating in docker goes against Docker's design. Every Dockerfile has its own version which including certain packages.  So  I think to build new image including the package your want maybe is the right way. Then you push your new image,  some guy can reuse it.

Comment: Most Dockerfiles I've seen have a line for updating the base Ubuntu image, so this should not be a problem. I just don't know how to get that unique key each time and then pass it to the adv.

Comment: I don't know what is adv. Please tell us more clearer, you want which unique key and what is the application scenario.

Comment: Sure, every time I run the apt-get update inside the docker container which was built off of a Dockerfile, i would get an error which I pasted above. In order to fix that, I would need to run the apt-key command above. Was looking for a way to automate the process, so added the fix apt-key command above to my Dockerfile. If the key changes, the Dockerfile will need to be updated manually which is a pain.

Comment: Are you using some custom PPA or something else like that?  You shouldn’t normally need to do that by hand, and if you do, it should be a consistent GPG key ID that you could “bake in” to your Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze   You're right I noticed the GPG key stays the same so I went ahead and just baked it into my Docker image (had to add a line to add that key before I could run the command to update the image)

Comment: `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys`